# Runtime alignment of structure members

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-alignment

Consider following `struct`:

```
struct SomeStruct
{
    int a;
    float b;
    double c;
};
```

As far as I know, when declaring an object of type `SomeStruct`, the address of first member of the `struct` (in this case `a`) is equal to the address of the object itself.

```
SomeStruct obj;
assert(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&obj) == reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&obj.a));
```

May I assume that run time address of `a` member respects the alignment requirements for `SomeStruct` even if `alignof(int) != alignof(SomeStruct)`?

Comment: Yes, since there **is** an object of type `SomeStruct` at address `&obj`, and `&obj` points to the same address as `&obj.a`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**9.2.19**
    A pointer to a standard-layout struct object, suitably converted using a  reinterpret_cast, points to its
    initial member (or if that member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides) and vice versa. [ Note:
    There might therefore be unnamed padding within a standard-layout struct object, but not at its beginning,
    as necessary to achieve appropriate alignment. —end note ].